# create a dictionary of unique nodes with unique properties from a csv in python to load in to neo4j

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, neo4j, cypher

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around the best way to do this; I can't figure out the dictionary structure to parse a csv and create various node dictionaries of unique nodes with unique properties to then load in to Neo4j.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import blah blah

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost")
input_location = "/path/to/file/file.csv"
output_location = "/path/to/dir/"
def main():

origin = {"PORT": [], "NUMBER": [], "CALL_SIGN": []}
ship = {"BOAT_NAME": [], "BOAT_NUMBER": []}
shipper = {"NAME": [], "STREET": [], "CITY": [], "ZIPCODE": []}
destination = {"COUNTRY": [], "CITY": []}
node_type_list = [origin, ship, shipper, destination]

with open(input_location, "rb") as ship_data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(ship_data, delimiter='|')
    print "parsing & uploading data\n"
    for row in reader:
        for node_type in node_type_list:
            for key in node_type:
                dict_load(node_type,key,row[key])
    send_nodes_to_graph(node_type_list)

def dict_load(node_type,key,value):
    try:
        if value not in node_type[key]:
            node_type[key].append(value)
    except Exception as e:
        print e

def send_nodes_to_graph(node_type_list):
    session = driver.session()
    session.run('''something_like_this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332698/can-a-python-dictionary-be-passed-as-neo4j-literal-maps/40333843#40333843''')
    session.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

my csv looks like this:

```
COUNTRY NUMBER  CALL_SIGN   PORT    BOAT_NAME   BOAT_NUMBER NAME    STREET  CITY    ST  ZIPCODE
D REP   91487   S DOMINGO   BALTIMORE   PESCADO 1276394 JH FWEICH   9874 LOMBARDO WAY   PORT ELIZABETH  NJ  8348
D REP   91487   S DOMINGO   VA BEACH    TROPIC  9872347 JH FWEICH   9874 LOMBARDO WAY   PORT ELIZABETH  NJ  8348
D REP   91487   S DOMINGO   VA BEACH    TROPIC  9872347 JH FWEICH   9874 LOMBARDO WAY   PORT ELIZABETH  NJ  8348
D REP   91487   S DOMINGO   VA BEACH    CAPRICORN   8761231 JH FWEICH   9874 LOMBARDO WAY   PORT ELIZABETH  NJ  8348
```

my dict structure currently produces this:

```
origin {'NUMBER': ['91487'], 'CALL_SIGN': ['S DOMINGO'], 'PORT': ['BALTIMORE', 'VA BEACH']}
```

but I think it needs to look more like this, in order to load only unique nodes in to Neo4j:

```
origin {'91487': {'CALL_SIGN': 'S DOMINGO', 'PORT': 'BALTIMORE'}}
origin {'91487': {'CALL_SIGN': 'S DOMINGO', 'PORT': 'VA BEACH'}}
ship {'1276394': {'BOAT_NAME': 'PESCADO'}}
shipper {'JH FWEICH': {'STREET': '9874 LOMBARDO WAY', 'CITY':'PORT ELIZABETH'}} 
etc....
```

Comment: Maybe a nested dict comprehension on each row? `{row['NUMBER']: {''CALL_SIGN': row['CALL_SIGN'], 'PORT': row['PORT']}}`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That's what I had originally, but I was hoping that there's a way to dynamically make and update these dicts, rather than specify where each column should go. But I think I've completely confused myself. haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?

```
origin = {"PORT", "NUMBER", "CALL_SIGN"}
ship = {"BOAT_NAME", "BOAT_NUMBER"}
shipper = {"NAME", "STREET", "CITY", "ZIPCODE"}
destination = {"COUNTRY", "CITY"}
node_type_list = [origin, ship, shipper, destination]

with open(input_location, "rb") as ship_data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(ship_data, delimiter='|')
    print "parsing & uploading data\n"
    for row in reader:
        dict_list = [{row["NUMBER"]: {key: row[key] for key in sublist}}for sublist in node_type_list]
```

This builds a list of dicts that map the `NUMBER`to a portion of the input dict.  I'm not familiar with neo4j, but hopefully this is more what you wanted.  Output should look like `[{'91487': {'CALL_SIGN': 'S DOMINGO', 'PORT': 'BALTIMORE'}}, {'91487': {'BOAT_NUMBER': '1276394', 'BOAT_NAME': 'PESCADO'}}, ...]`

Comment: Thanks for the help - I think this is in the right direction. That works for only the origin node, but not the ship, shipper or destination nodes. The other nodes would need to use a unique identifier(and their own dict_list), I think. I'll update the question to reflect that. So, I think it would be something like:  
`[{'91487': {'CALL_SIGN': 'S DOMINGO', 'PORT': 'BALTIMORE'}}]`
`[{1276394':{'BOAT_NAME': 'PESCADO'}}]`
`[{JH FWEICH':{'STREET':....}}]`

Comment: maybe I can set it by using the first key in each sublist?

Comment: I think that worked. Change each sublist `{ }` to `[ ]`, set the first element in each sublist to whichever you prefer to use for that node dict key and then change `dict_list = [{row["NUMBER"]: {key: row[key] for key in sublist}}for sublist in node_type_list]` to `dict_list = [{row[sublist[0]]: {key: row[key] for key in sublist[1:]}} for sublist in node_type_list]`

Answer (score 0):

for clarity, I wanted to show the changes I made that @PatrickHaugh led me to. I wanted to give him credit for the logic behind the answer so I accepted it and am adding the update here. His Suggestion is below and my actual version that makes the correct structure follows.

```
origin = {"PORT", "NUMBER", "CALL_SIGN"}
ship = {"BOAT_NAME", "BOAT_NUMBER"}
shipper = {"NAME", "STREET", "CITY", "ZIPCODE"}
destination = {"COUNTRY", "CITY"}
node_type_list = [origin, ship, shipper, destination]

with open(input_location, "rb") as ship_data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(ship_data, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        dict_list = [{row["NUMBER"]: {key: row[key] for key in sublist}}for sublist in node_type_list]
```

output:
`[{'91487': {'CALL_SIGN': 'S DOMINGO', 'PORT': 'BALTIMORE'}}, {'91487': {'BOAT_NUMBER': '1276394', 'BOAT_NAME': 'PESCADO'}}, ...]`

** correct output version:

```
origin = ["NUMBER", "PORT", "CALL_SIGN"] 
# moved the keys around so that the first key is the identifier for the sublist
ship = ["BOAT_NUMBER", "BOAT_NAME"] 
shipper = ["NAME", "STREET", "CITY", "ZIPCODE"]
destination = ["COUNTRY", "CITY"]
node_type_list = [origin, ship, shipper, destination]

with open(input_location, "rb") as ship_data:
    reader = csv.DictReader(ship_data, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        # uses first element in sublist to identify dict section, uses following elements to populate dict properties
        dict_list = [{row[sublist[0]]: {key: row[key] for key in sublist[1:]}} for sublist in node_type_list]
```

output: 
`[{'91487': {'PORT': 'VA BEACH', 'CALL_SIGN': 'S DOMINGO'}}, {'8761231': {'BOAT_NAME': 'CAPRICORN'}}, {'JH FWEICH': {'CITY': 'PORT ELIZABETH'...}}]`